# Python subprocess with mongo-connector waits indefinitely or does not wait at all

Tags: python, subprocess

I've written a program that syncs MongoDB collections with Elasticsearch on a nightly basis:

```
command = """python connector.py -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic_doc_manager.py --oplog-ts oplogstatus.txt --namespace-set db.collection --dest-namespace-set newIndex"""

subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command),shell=False).wait()

...do some more stuff...
```

In the above approach, "do some more stuff" never gets executed, though I know the process has finished. If I change the subprocess to `subprocess.call(command)`, regardless of the shell setting, then "do some more stuff" appears to happen prematurely (before the subprocess finishes).

I've read the docs, as well as many of the other questions that cover similar issues, but I still can't seem to get a good sense of what's happening here. I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Does `connector.py` demonizes itself? `call()` is equivalent to `Popen().wait()` -- if they behave differently; you are running a different code. If they've returned; the process is dead but the daemon that it might have created may live on.

Comment: It demonizes itself; keeps a connection open to write database changes at a given interval. Very dumb that I overlooked that, given it is exactly what the connector is made for. Not sure I can pass parameters to the connector to shut it down once the initial sync is complete.